# Foreign and primary keys question

Tags: foreign-key

I have have looked for an answer for my questions everywhere but they seem confusing to me.Can a foreign key be a primary key in the same table? Can a foreign key be a primary key in another table?

Can a foreign key take values that repeat themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with definitions then go into differences.

**Primary Key**
There can be only one Primary Key per table.  It is one of the candidate keys.  A candidate key is a key comprised of a column or group of columns that uniquely identify the row.  In SQL Server none of the values can be NULL but I can't say for certain that is true in other DBMSs.

**Foreign Key**
A foreign key is a column or group of columns that `relate` two tables together.    Typically this is called a parent/child relationship.  So for example a child table will have a `Parent_Id` column that refers back to the `Parent` table.  This relationship is one of the cornerstones of the `relational` part of the RDBMS (Relational DataBase Management System).  There can be multiple foreign keys on a table and in fact a foreign key can even relate a table back to itself.

**Comparison**
As you can see they really have nothing to do with each other.  The column(s) that make up the `Primary Key` can be the same column(s) that are used in a `Foreign Key` or even multiple `Foreign Keys` but they don't have to be.  The `Parent` table must related by one of the `Candidate Keys` but that does not have to be the `Primary Key`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a duplicate but I cannot find it
Typically another table and even some definitions state another table

Repeating values is the norm for a FK

FK point to the PK of another (or the same table) is the common configuration.  In MSSQL it can be a column(s) with a unique constraint (and not PK).  The row must be uniquely identified.

Here is an example of a single table
Assume each employee has exactly one boss
The person at the top works for them-self
BossID would be a FK in the same table
Yes BossID would repeat if more than one person worked for that boss

```
EmpID  (PK) 
BossID (FK EmpID)
```

An invoice table with multiple reference to a the same customer

```
InvoiceID  (PK) 
CustomerID (FK Customer.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking three questions:

> Can a foreign key be a primary key in the same table?

The answer is *yes*.

Here is an example. Suppose that you have a table `Projects`, with columns `ProjectId, Name, Description, Manager, Budget`, and also a table `SpecialProjects`, that contains additional information about certain special projects, with other columns, referenced by other tables, etc. So you have in this table a foreign key for the `Project` table, which contains the “general” informations about those special project. This foreign key, let’s call it FkProjectId, is *also* a primary key for the `SpecialProjects` table.

> Can a foreign key be a primary key in another table?

A foreign key in a table `B` that refers to a table `A` is a column such that all its values *must* be present also in the primary key column of `A`. So, the question is meaningless if you intend that a foreign key is two different column (this of course is impossible), while the answer to this question is *always* “yes” if you intend that the values of the foreign keys are also values in a primary key in another table.

> Can a foreign key take values that repeat themselves?

The answer is “yes”.

Consider the above example: in the table `Projects` the column `Manager` is a foreign key for an `Employee` table. If an employee can manage more than one project, then different rows in the `Project` table have the same value in the column `Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

This should clarify things for you:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179610.aspx